# Using php/pdo to display sql data on website, no luck

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I know this is probably something simple, but I have searched for hours the past few days and I'm ready to jump out of my one-story building.

1. Have a basic site for testing, literally nothing on it but opening/closing html tags.
2. A very basic table in a data base, using phpmyadmin to access it.
3. Trying to get table contents to display on the basic website.

Was using mysqli_ or mysql_ style in the php to access the data for a while with no luck.. Have since been reading about PDO and found numerous tutorials on how to use it. I feel like what I'm trying to do should be so simple but I've tried copying what I've found on this site and other tutorials to the T and the site still does not display the data.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$userdb", $username, $password);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Monday";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    while($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['Name'] . '<br />';
        }

    $conn = null;

    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Basically the website will display everything after the first -> in this case after the $conn-> but none of the actual table data.

I've tried about 50 different ways at least from numerous sites and I'm just lost now I guess..

Side note: I do have php forms on the same site that when submitted successfully insert data into the table, so I know I am able to connect to the db and table and INSERT, its just the issue of SELECT I can't get.

Thanks for any help

EDITED: to add fetchAll

Comment: You're not doing any error checking on your query. Add a `var_dump($result->ErrorInfo()` and `var_dump($conn->ErrorInfo())` to see if there are any errors being generated from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added both but it still just prints everything after -> so the site just displays: exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); $sql = "SELECT * FROM Monday"; $result = $conn->query($sql); var_dump($result->ErrorInfo()); var_dump($conn->ErrorInfo()); while($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { echo $row['Name'] . '
'; } $conn = null; } catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }  ?>

Comment: If it's printing out your PHP, then it's not being interpreted properly. Do you have the right `<?php` tag at the start of the file? Does the file name end in .php?

Comment: Maybe that's my issue. Yes tags are correct around the code. But the actual file is an index.html file for a website.. Can I simply change that to .php ?

Comment: Yep. That will get the server to run it as PHP, so the code will run.

Comment: or copy it and name it .phps on your server and provide the link

Comment: Ok changed the file to .php and it no longer prints out the code, so that seems to have solved that. Now it just says Could not find driver.. So at least I know what to look for as far as errors, Thanks a ton for the help, I knew it was simple haha

Comment: @ChrisWeems - no problem. Good luck, and if you get stuck feel free to give me a prod.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the method `fetch()` in your loop, which only fetches the next single row of your results. Replace it with `fetchAll()` and it should work.

More information about the `fetchAll()` method:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

And for testing purposes you could set the PDO error mode to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Thanks I made that change and have had that on there before, the site still just prints out mostly code rather than table data.. Is there anything else in an html file to implement to simply display the info other than the php code? I've tried placing it between basic tags but still the same

Comment: can u upload the whole file?

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Should be;

```
while($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```